# Scrollable column in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]I want to make my screen scrollable but that is not happening. I am making an app where i want to show an image,title and description. I have succesfully shown the data but now want to make screen scrollable. I also want to add an app bar but then two app bar appears one below the other.

**Here is my code:**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:kmitra/app_screens/fragment_topheadlines.dart';

import 'News.dart';

class Newsdetail extends StatefulWidget {
  final String value_image, value_description, value_title;

  /*String value_image,value_description;
 int index;*/

  Newsdetail(
      {Key key,
      @required this.value_image,
      this.value_description,
      this.value_title})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _newsdetail createState() => _newsdetail();
}

class _newsdetail extends State<Newsdetail> {
  _newsdetail();

  // List<News> dataList = List();
  bool _isLoading = false;
  BuildContext context1;

  Future loadyourData() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();

      loadyourData();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
              child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child: Image.network(
              widget.value_image, //image
            )),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6.0, 8.0, 0, 8.0),
              child: Text(
                widget.value_title, //title
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: Text(
              widget.value_description, //descrpition
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
            )),
          ],
        ),
      ))),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You need pageView widget (like app tour start in app)?     https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-pageview-in-flutter-with-custom-transitions-581d9ea6dded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by using rows inside the column widget and then using SinglechildScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

Use   [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html)

```
   @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {

            return Scaffold(
              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                   child: Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                        child: Image.network(
                      widget.value_image,              //image

                    )),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6.0, 8.0, 0, 8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        widget.value_title,             //title
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                      widget.value_description,       //descrpition
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                    )),
                ],
              ),
                  ))),
            );
          }
        }
```

As in comments instead of scroll body use

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Text(
                      widget.value_description,       //descrpition
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                    )),
```

OR

```
Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                      widget.value_description,       //descrpition
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                    )),
```

Comment: is your view so long that it needs scrolling? can you post a screenshot where it is clear what needs to be scrolled

Comment: I feel this is a child widget not a parent widget in which scroll is needed.

Comment: Actually the description is big and needs scrolling.

Comment: This does work for description individually..i want to scroll the whole page.

Comment: you want scroll both? you said "Actually the description is big and needs scrolling".  Better provide a screenshot with highlighting the issue

Comment: I have added an image where i need to scroll the whole page vertically so that i could see the remaining news below.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use Listview or SingleChildScrollView For Scrollable View in
>   body
>
> ```
> ListView(
>       shrinkWrap: true,
>       padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
>       children: <Widget>[
>         //Your Column Childrens
>       ]
>     )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SingleChildScrollView` in `Container` widget like this

```
Container(
  child:  SingleChildScrollView(
    child:  Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        _showChild1(),
       other child widgets
        ...
      ]
    )
  )
);
```